# Rails tests not running due to apparently pending migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a very strange problem in which running `rails test` seems to be dropping a table in my test database. I can drop, create and migrate a database, then use `psql` to check the correct tables are there. If I then run `rails t` however, I am told `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "groups" does not exist`, and checking with `psql` shows that the table is indeed now missing. Rails then tells me I have 24 pending migrations, which is all my migrations.

Comment: try `RAILS_ENV=test rails db:drop db:create db:migrate`

Comment: This doesn't solve it I'm afraid.

Comment: Rails creates the test database from schema.rb , is the table missing in that file?

Comment: Ah that's it thank you, I'd added an enum type that schema.rb didn't support and needed to switch to SQL format, thank you. Happy to accept an answer if you write one.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed with

```
rails db:setup --trace
```